# Count no of duplicates in multidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I need to count the no of duplicates in an multidimensional array and give alert if duplicates found.

```
Arr =[[2,"sk"],[3,"df"],[7,"uz"],[3,"df"],[7,"gh"]]
```

Only exact count require like [3,"df"] at 2 nd position  equals [3,"df"], at 4 th position
Expected Output
Count :1
Alert duplicate data found

Comment: If the input array was `[[2,"sk"],[5,"df"],[7,"uz"],[3,"df"],[7,"gh"]]` would this have one duplicate or no duplicates? (`[5,"df"]` vs `[3,"df"]`)

Comment: No these duplicates not counted

Comment: What about `[2,"sk"]` and `["sk",2]`?

Comment: Would it be possible to have a `[21, "sk"]` and a `[2, "1sk"]`?

Comment: Need perfect combination [2,"sk"]  must be equal to  [2,"sk"]   then only it counts

Answer (score 1):

You could map to a stringified version of the inner arrays and then create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of these and then calculate the difference in length of the items in the set and the original array:

```js
const input = [
  [2, "sk"], [3, "df"], [7, "uz"], [3, "df"], [7, "gh"],
  [5, "df"], [21, "sk"], [2, "1sk"]
];

const duplicate_count = input.length - new Set( input.map(JSON.stringify) ).size;

console.log(duplicate_count);
```

Comment: Always first value is no and second is string
Only counts the exact combination
Like 
[3,"df"]  at second position equal to
[3,"df"] at fourth combination

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` to get only the values, then `sort`, then count duplicates with `reduce` like this:

```js
const input = [
  [2, "sk"],
  [3, "df"],
  [7, "uz"],
  [3, "df"],
  [7, "gh"],
];

const result = input
  .map(([, value]) => value)
  .sort()
  .reduce(
    (acc, cur, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => (cur === last ? acc + 1 : acc),
    0
  );

console.log(`Count: ${result}${result && ' Alert duplicate data found'}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple little function to return the number of dupes found

```js
let arr =[[2,"sk"],[3,"df"],[7,"uz"],[3,"df"],[7,"gh"],[2,"sk"],[7,"uz"]]

function getNumDupes(a) {
   return a.length-
arr.reduce((b,a)=>{if (!b.includes(a.join(""))) b.push(a.join("")); return b;},[]).length 
}

console.log(getNumDupes(arr) + ' duplicates found');
```