# Need to find or count duplicates in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, reactjs

I need to count the no of duplicates in an multidimensional array and give alert if duplicates found.

Arr =[[2,"sk"],[3,"df"],[7,"uz"],[3,"df"],[7,"gh"]]

Suggestions:
Count can be done in this manner that if arr[0] position is equals to next coming positions then it must give a count & needs to check both values combination same.
And then for arr[1] position to check for next coming positions and so on for other position till last

Only counts the exact combination
Like
[3,"df"]  at second position equal to
[3,"df"] at fourth combination

Expected Output Count :1 Alert duplicate data found

Comment: What would the count be for `[[2,"sk"],[2,"sk"],[3,"df"],[3,"df"],[3,"df"]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953044/14454939) from the original question (except that I've got three items like `[3, "df"]` in the input array) is:

```js
const input = [
  [2, "sk"], [3, "df"], [7, "uz"], [3, "df"], [7, "gh"],
  [5, "df"], [21, "sk"], [2, "1sk"], [3, "df"]
];

const duplicate_count = input.length - new Set( input.map(JSON.stringify) ).size;

console.log(duplicate_count);
```

If the count for `[[3,"df"],[3,"df"],[3,"df"]]` should be one instead of two then perhaps something like:

```js
const input = [
  [2, "sk"], [3, "df"], [7, "uz"], [3, "df"], [7, "gh"],
  [5, "df"], [21, "sk"], [2, "1sk"], [3, "df"]
];

const duplicate_count = [
  ...input
    .map(JSON.stringify)
    .reduce( (acc, v) => acc.set(v, (acc.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map() )
    .values()
].filter((v) => v > 1).length;

console.log(duplicate_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` to concatenate the numbers and strings, then `sort`. Finally, `reduce` the array to the duplicates count.

```js
const input = [
  [2, "sk"],
  [3, "df"],
  [7, "uz"],
  [3, "df"],
  [7, "gh"],
  [7, "df"],
];

const result = input
  .map(([number, string]) => number + string)
  .sort()
  .reduce(
    (acc, cur, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => (cur === last ? acc + 1 : acc),
    0
  );

console.log(`Count: ${result}${result && ' Alert duplicate data found'}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let arr =[[2,"sk"],[3,"df"],[7,"uz"],[3,"df"],[7,"gh"],[2,"sk"],[7,"uz"]]
    
    function getNumDupes(a) {
       return a.length-
    arr.reduce((b,a)=>{if (!b.includes(a.join(""))) b.push(a.join("")); return b;},[]).length 
    }
    
    console.log(getNumDupes(arr) + ' duplicates found');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to iterate the array and then filter and check length if found more than 1, set an entry into Map which holds a key value pair and will keep 1 entry for same key and then can check the size.

```js
let arr =[[2,"sk"],[3,"df"],[7,"uz"],[3,"df"],[7,"gh"]];

let map = new Map();
arr.forEach(e1 => 
                 arr.filter(e2 => e1[0]===e2[0] && e1[1]===e2[1]).length > 1
                 ? map.set(`${e1[0]}-${e1[1]}`,1) 
                 : null
            );

console.log(`${map.size} duplicate found`);
```